# Usage of lens for concise update of records

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell. I'm developing a game-like simulation. I try to use lenses to update the state of the world.

Current iteration of code works, but looks clumsy. I am trying to improve it, e.g. I would like to:

1. Get rid of direct enumeration of `q1` and so on, with usage of `quantityPolymorph` and others in them. Problem is that partial application won't help since the function which gets applied is "in the middle" of arguments;
2. Get rid of incrementQuantity. I'd like something like `fmap (+1)`, but since `Quantity` is not an instance of `Functor`, I can't do that. I can't make `Quantity` an instance because it has kind `*`. Is there a more concise way, w/o lambda?
3. Update world with just lenses, if possible. It looks like simple dispatching and I think it might be possible to move away from direct specification of what lens (i.e. `quantityPolymorpth`) should be called for which argument (`f`).

**Important note**: however the `updateWorld` never emits `Nothing` at the moment, I want to keep it returning a `Maybe` because later at some point it will return `Nothing`s as well.

How can I refactor my code? Are there other things amiss with it?

The source follows.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad
import System.Random

data Quantity = Quantity Integer deriving (Show)

instance Random Quantity where
    randomR (Quantity lo, Quantity hi) g =
        let rand = randomR (lo, hi) g
            (r, g1) = rand
        in (Quantity r, g1)
    random g =
        let rand = random g
            (r, g1) = rand
        in (Quantity r, g1)

instance Eq Quantity where
    (==) (Quantity q1) (Quantity q2) = q1 == q2

instance Ord Quantity where
    (<=) (Quantity q1) (Quantity q2) = q1 <= q2

instance Num Quantity where
    (+) (Quantity q1) (Quantity q2) = Quantity (q1 + q2)
    (*) (Quantity q1) (Quantity q2) = Quantity (q1 * q2)
    (-) (Quantity q1) (Quantity q2) = Quantity (q1 - q2)
    abs (Quantity q) = Quantity (abs q)
    signum (Quantity q) = Quantity (signum q)
    fromInteger i = Quantity i
-------------------------------

data QuantityHolder = QuantityHolder { _quantityPolymorph  :: Quantity
                                     , _quantityTeamPlayer :: Quantity
                                     , _quantityLoneWolf   :: Quantity
                                     } deriving (Show)

$(makeLenses ''QuantityHolder)
-------------------------------

data Fighter = TeamPlayer
             | LoneWolf
             | Polymorph
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
-------------------------------

data World = World {
    _quantities :: QuantityHolder
} deriving (Show)

$(makeLenses ''World)

incrementQuantity (Quantity q) = Quantity (q + 1)

updateWorld :: Maybe World -> Fighter -> Maybe World
updateWorld (Just w) f =
    case f of
        Polymorph ->
            Just $ q1 w
        TeamPlayer ->
            Just $ q2 w
        LoneWolf ->
            Just $ q3 w
    where q1 = over quantities . over quantityPolymorph $ incrementQuantity
          q2 = over quantities . over quantityTeamPlayer $ incrementQuantity
          q3 = over quantities . over quantityLoneWolf $ incrementQuantity
```

Comment: I have taken the liberty to edit the question to make it more suitable for a code review, which I believe is what you were after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateWorld` of @Changaco can still be improved. I'll show it gradually so you can see what's going on.

Firstly, we can eliminate duplication in `case` statement and use lens composition to eliminate second `over`:

```
quantity Polymorph = quantityPolymorph
quantity TeamPlayer = quantityTeamPlayer
quantity LoneWolf = quantityLoneWolf

updateWorld :: Fighter -> World -> World
updateWorld fighter w = increment (quantity fighter) w where
        increment field = over (quantities . field) (+1)
```

Then we can go pointfree. Pointfree is all about readability so don't do it whenever you feel readability is harmed. With coding experience more and more code will become readable for you.

```
updateWorld = increment . quantity where
    increment field = over (quantities . field) (+1)
```

Then we replace `over` with a more specialized version of it from `Control.Lens.Setter`:

```
updateWorld = increment . quantity where
    increment field = (quantities . field) +~ 1
```

Now it seems beneficial to inline `increment`. I'll do in 2 steps. First, I make the actual parameter of `increment` explicit:

```
updateWorld field = increment $ quantity field where
    increment field = (quantities . field) +~ 1
```

Then I inline:

```
updateWorld :: Fighter -> World -> World
updateWorld field = (quantities . quantity field) +~ 1
```

Another way to improve could be to use a `Map` or an `Array` for `QuantityHolder`:

```
data World = World { _quantities :: M.Map Fighter Quantity }
```

Below is full source using `Map`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Lens
import System.Random
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe

newtype Quantity = Quantity Integer
    deriving (Eq,Num,Ord,Random,Show)

data Fighter = TeamPlayer
             | LoneWolf
             | Polymorph
               deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

data World = World { _quantities :: M.Map Fighter Quantity }
    deriving (Show)
$(makeLenses ''World)

atFighter i = at i . iso fromJust Just

updateWorld :: Fighter -> World -> World
updateWorld field = (quantities . atFighter field) +~ 1
```

But it really depends on the usage scenarios you plan for `World`.

Also note that lens interact with state monad transformer pretty well, so you may consider

```
updateWorldS :: Fighter -> State World Quantity
updateWorldS field = (quantities . atFighter field) <+= 1
```

Note that `World` is not passed in explicitly any more. And the type is more general than that, so you can combine state with IO and other monads should you wish:

```
updateWorldS :: MonadState World m => Fighter -> m Quantity
```

If you want to be able to report any extra value from `updateWorld` you can use the existing state monad:

```
updateWorldS :: Fighter -> State World Bool
updateWorldS field = (quantities . atFighter field) <+= 1 >> return errorBool where
      errorBool = False -- or True
```

Or `MonadPlus` if you don't want to just report failure without extra info:

```
updateWorldS field = (quantities . atFighter field) <+= 1 >> when errorBool mzero where
      errorBool = False
```

Or `MonadError` if you want to supply an error value (of any type):

```
updateWorldS4 field = (quantities . atFighter field) <+= 1 >> when errorBool (throwError "Game over")
```

Comment: That's some real Haskell power! However, I want to keep the `Maybe` for `updateWorld` since it will return `Nothing` a bit later, when more logic will be implemented. I believe it complicates the point-free.

Comment: As you accept `Maybe World` and return `Maybe World` there are 4 possible cases (Nonthing - Nothing, Just - Nothing, Nothing-Just and Just-Just). Do you need them all? What does accepting (resp. returning) no world means? Since there have been too many improvements to your code it's better to create a new question for that. Put there a minimal code example that illustrates why you think you need `Nothing` in the first place. The possibilities are numerous - for example, you could have returned id function if you don't want to have world modified,so we want to know your intent and not mere code

Comment: I want to be able to stop updating at some point. In such case I would return `Nothing` and outer loop in `main` would stop calling `updateWorld` then.

Comment: Edited my answer to include many ways to return extra data along with modifying world in case of monadic approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Get rid of direct enumeration of q1 and so on, with usage of quantityPolymorph and others in them. Problem is that partial application won't help since the function which gets applied is "in the middle" of arguments

That's not a problem, you can do partial application in any order, it's just more verbose.

> Get rid of incrementQuantity. I'd like something like fmap (+1), but since Quantity is not an instance of Functor, I can't do that. I can't make Quantity an instance because it has kind *. Is there a more concise way, w/o lambda?

You don't need `fmap`, a simple `(+1)` works. If I'm not mistaken, under the hood the compiler uses `fromInteger` to convert the `1` literal to a `Quantity`.

---

Here is what I have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Lens
import System.Random

newtype Quantity = Quantity Integer
    deriving (Eq,Num,Ord,Random,Show)

data QuantityHolder = QuantityHolder { _quantityPolymorph  :: Quantity
                                     , _quantityTeamPlayer :: Quantity
                                     , _quantityLoneWolf   :: Quantity
                                     } deriving (Show)
$(makeLenses ''QuantityHolder)

data Fighter = TeamPlayer
             | LoneWolf
             | Polymorph
               deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

data World = World { _quantities :: QuantityHolder }
    deriving (Show)
$(makeLenses ''World)

updateWorld :: Fighter -> World -> World
updateWorld fighter w =
    case fighter of
        Polymorph -> increment quantityPolymorph w
        TeamPlayer -> increment quantityTeamPlayer w
        LoneWolf -> increment quantityLoneWolf w
    where increment field = over quantities . over field $ (+1)
```

I didn't really look into the lens stuff.

Note the use of `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to get rid of the boring instance declarations.

A main function to do a simple test:

```
main = do
    let w = World $ QuantityHolder 0 0 0
    print $ updateWorld Polymorph $ updateWorld LoneWolf w
```